# Why does this function only output the second value? Is there any way for a function to output two outputs?

Tags: javascript, function, syntax

I'm new to Javascript, but have experience with other languages. I was trying to get a function to give me two outputs but it wasn't working, and ultimatley with the syntax I was using, I discovered that it was only giving me the second value I inputed. Is there a reason for this? I can't think of any way that you would want to use this type of syntax if the first value is ignored entirely.

My code:

```
var a;
    
var b;
var c;
    
var d = false;
var e = "";
    
var f = "";
    
var g = false;

a = returnTwoValues();
console.log("A: " + a);
    
b, c = returnTwoValues();
console.log("B: " + b);
console.log("C: " + c);
    
d, e = returnTwoValues();
console.log("D: " + d);
console.log("E: " + e);
    
f = returnTwoValues();
console.log("F: " + f);
    
g = returnTwoValues();
console.log("G: " + g);

function returnTwoValues(){
  return true, "Hello";
}
```

It's Output:

```
"A: Hello"
"B: undefined"
"C: Hello"
"D: false"
"E: Hello"
"F: Hello"
"G: Hello"
```

the same thing was outputted when i changed returnTwoValues() to

```
function returnTwoValues(){
  return "Hi", "Hello";
}
```

Comment: You could put multiple values into an object or array, depending on the semantics of those values.  But the comma operator simply doesn't do what you're expecting it to do here.

Comment: Comma in JS doesn't work like in GO.

`expr1`, `expr2`, `expr3`, …
One or more expressions, the last of which is returned as the value of the compound expression.
Here docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_operator#parameters

Comment: In JS a function can only return a single value. If you need more than one value, you can wrap them into another data structure. For instance an array. `return [true, "Hello"]`